# Permission can not be effective immediately after modifying

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Environment :

- wso2 API-M + wso2 Identity server (Key manager) and they shared the
  same user store.
- 2 service providers(publisher and store) and 2 identity
  providers(Google and Facebook) in the carbon.super tenant.
- APIM SSO service is enabled and issuer IDs follow above.
- Enable OAuth2.0 users(Google and Facebook) to login.
- 3 tenants (carbon.super , TA and TB) in the environment.
- Publisher SP and Store SP are both in SaaS mode.

Step:

1.Super admin login to carbon UI.

2.Edit role "everyone" and set creater, subscriber and publisher permissions.

3.Social account login to Publisher fail. (401 error)

4.In 1~8 hours, social account login again and it works.

5.Super admin login to carbon UI and remove all permission from the role "everyone" and it can be effective immediately.(Social account can't login.)

6.Repeat step 1 and 2.

7.Same as step 3.

8.Same as step 4.

I'm not sure if I have to configure any system setting thus the permission can be effective immediately.

Comment: I believe there's authorization cache in place, see at the bottom of the user-mgt.xml  , try to disable the cache (AuthorizationCacheEnabled = false) EDIT: hmm.. the persmission should be reflected in the DB immediately and cache purged, so - it's just a hint, not a solution :(

Comment: Hello, is there any way to let the permission be effective immediately without changing AuthorizationCacheEnabled?

Comment: Hi, Do you have shared registry as well in your setup? Also please let us know, that you have external user store which connected with both IS and APIM or you are using shared user store for both products. Because, Usually default cache update time is 15 minutes. So I'm wondering why it takes 1 - 8 hours to update. Anyway did tried to disable Authorization Cache as  @GabrielVince mentioned?

Comment: Well - in the proper cluster setup there's shared Hazelcast cluster. Is it set up (in axis2.xml)? It would worth to see where are the permissions cached, as up to the versions 5.1.0 (including) there's a bug which effectively places the cache timeout to the future, so you cannot count with 15 minutes without cache invalidation.

Comment: Sorry for replying late, 

Charitha , IS and APIM use the same external user store and it's refer to official document.

GabrielVince , I'll check it and reply ASAP and thanks for your hands.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the details. As Gabriel mentioned if it cloud happen due to that known bug, I would like to reproduce the issue locally to analyze it further. Then we can debug the product and identify the issue easily. So could you please let me know your IS and APIM versions and also the patch details if you have applied any.